# how to align the text middle of bakground image in css

Tags: css

I want align the content in middle of the background image in css. 
I was used the code like

```
 section.center_content {
     background: url(../images/center_bg.jpg) center no-repeat;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
     font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     margin-bottom: 40px;
     background-size:100%;
     height:190px;
 }
 .ticker-content {
     vertical-align:middle;
 }
 .ticker-content h1 {
     color:#FFFFFF;
     font-size:45px;
 }
 .ticker-content h2 {
     color:#BFBFBF;
     font-size:35px;
 }
 .ticker-content p {
     color:#BFBFBF;
     font-size:20px;
 }
```

Please give a solution. thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

Add the following properties to your `section.center_content`:

```
section.center_content {
    background:blue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    height:190px;
    width:100px;

    /*Vertically center*/
    display:table-cell;    /*This makes the div behave like a table cell*/
    vertical-align:middle; /*This property is only available on table cells*/

    /*Horizontal center*/
    text-align:center;     /*This you know centers text horizontally*/
}

.ticker-content{
    /*Remove vertical-align:middle; from here*/
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/CysQ8/)**

P.S. And keep this [wonderful article](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/) for future reference.

Comment: If you are able to, please provide explanations for these actions. Thanks!

Comment: @Dropout yes, I am adding it. Two mins please.

Comment: @Dropout Glad to be of help :)

Comment: overall move left side of the website not in full view.

Comment: @user3265980 It would be great if you could share your HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

The css property vertical-align applies to inline elements and table-cell element.

So add a display:table-cell to your element to be align in the middle.

Comment: if add display:table-cell, it's move to left side of the page. not in actual view

Answer (score 0):

You can always use line-height property that equalls to the height of the container that it is.